# Oscillating Values in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cycle

So I need to have 2 values oscillate back and forth.
Say `2` the first time, and `4` the second time. Repeat from the top.

So I wrote the below generator function which works. Each time it is called via `next` it returns the subsequent value, and then repeats from the top.

For the sake of learning, and improving, NOT opinion, is there a better way? In Python there always seems to be a better way, and I like to learn them so as to improve my skills.

The "main code" is just to show an example of the generator, oscillator, in use, and is not the primary use of the oscillator.

```
## Main code
go_Osci = g_Osci()
for i in xrange(10):
    print("Value: %i") %(go_Osci.next())

## Generator
def g_Osci():
    while True:
        yield 2
        yield 4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way.  [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) was designed explicitly for this task:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> for i in cycle([2, 4]):
...     print i
...
2
4
2
4
2
4
2
# Goes on forever
```

You can also use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to only cycle a certain number of times:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(cycle([2, 4])):
...     if i == 10:  # Only loop 10 times
...         break
...     print j
...
2
4
2
4
2
4
2
4
2
4
>>>
```

Comment: Good stuff thanks. Using that I can also remove the "while loop" I am using in my actual code. Always a better way in Python.

Comment: @iCodez also show him to use enumerate and break at 10

Comment: @Hackaholic - Well, he didn't ask for that, but it sounds good to mention it.

Comment: ICodez, wow, you must read minds, as I was just over at endmemo.com/program/python/ and docs.python.org learning more about "itertools" and wondering if i might use "repeat" to limit the loop. I come back here, and you have the answer. Thanks. I am now learning the other uses of "intertools" like "takewhile" and "dropwhile". Cool and useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly two years after asking this question, I would like to share what I ultimately came up with to fit my needs. Using inline `for` loops to cycle thru some alternating values was often too static and inflexible for what I needed.

I kept going back to my generator solution, as it proved to be more flexible in my applications--I could call `next()` on it at anytime and from anywhere in my scripts.

I then hit upon using `cycle` in my generator. By "priming" the generator with a list of desired values at instance inception, I can have access to alternating values as needed anywhere in my script. I can also "prime" more instances with differing values as needed.

The added benefit is that the underlying code is generalized, and so able to be treated as an importable module.

I call this construct of using a generator to produce alternating values an "Oscillator."

I hope this may benefit someone in the future.

Python 2.7.10

```
    # Imports #
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import cycle

    # Generators
def g_Oscillator(l_Periods):
"""Takes LIST and primes gen, then yields VALUES from list as each called/next()"""
g_Result = cycle(l_Periods)
for value in g_Result:
    yield value

    # Main Code
go_52Oscillator = g_Oscillator([5, 2]) ## Primed Ocscillator
go_34Oscillator = g_Oscillator([3, 4]) ## Primed Ocscillator
go_ABCOscillator = g_Oscillator(["A", "B", "C"]) ## Primed Ocscillator
for i in xrange(5):
    print(go_34Oscillator.next())
print()

for i in xrange(5):
    print(go_52Oscillator.next())
print()

for i in xrange(5):
    print(go_ABCOscillator.next())
```